# Attaching dynamic variables to ajax callback function

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a loop that sends ajax requests. I want to include the loop index in my ajax callback function:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    $.ajax({
        data: "index="+i
        success: function (data) {
            //I want to be able to see the variable (i) here
            //since the request is async, it returns the last index on all
            $("#div"+i).append(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap it up in a closure. This should do it:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $.ajax({
            data: "index="+i
            success: function (data) {
                //I want to be able to see the variable (i) here
                //since the request is async, it returns the last index on all
                $("#div"+i).append(data);
            }
        })
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a closure around your ajax request to preserve the value of `i` as local for the request callback function:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data` to return the index parameter as well as the rest of the data

```
1: REST OF DATA HERE
```

The just strip the index from the data string.